# Create map layout focused on selected feature using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I'm working in a plugin in QGIS (3.4.5) and I want to create a map in layout designer focused on my selected feature. I want to add table of attributes of the selected feature to the map too.

1. Select a feature by attributes,
2. Zoom to that feature,
3. Create a map in layout designer focused on that feature,
4. Add a table with the attributes of the selected feature to the map

The zoom is working on my feature selected in Qgis but my map created in layout designer is not focused on my selected feature. How can I do this please?

Here is my code:

```
layer_DI = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("TDJ_DI")[0]
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = 'Layout1'

layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()

for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

expr = QgsExpression("\"DI\"='1'""")

selection = layer_TDJ_DI.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))

ids = [s.id() for s in selection]

layer_DI.selectByIds(ids)

iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(layer_DI)

map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)

map.setRect(20, 20, 200, 300)

ms = QgsMapSettings()

ms.setLayers([layer_DI])
rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(0.1)

ms.setExtent(rect)

map.zoomToExtent(rect)

map.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)

map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(180, 180, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

Comment: What it your question? If you are asking a code releated question you need to include code in the question or it will get closed

Comment: How can I do that ?

Comment: Your question reads more like a wishlist than a request for help on a specific problem. I recommend focusing on one issue at a time else your question will be closed as '[needs more focus](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions#:~:text=Needs%20more%20focus,of%20the%20problem.)'. Please familiarise yourself with the [the Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [How to ask a good question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regarding zooming to selected features, refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230223/128665)

Comment: The zoom is working on Qgis but not in my layout created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the extent of your map item to the bounding box of the selected feature(s). Use `layer_DI.boundingBoxOfSelected()` to get the bbox.

```py
# I select the layer in a different way but that should not affect the result
layer_DI = iface.activeLayer()
project = QgsProject.instance()
manager = project.layoutManager()
layoutName = 'Layout1'

layouts_list = manager.printLayouts()

for layout in layouts_list:
    if layout.name() == layoutName:
        manager.removeLayout(layout)

layout = QgsPrintLayout(project)
layout.initializeDefaults()
layout.setName(layoutName)
manager.addLayout(layout)

# select feature(s)
expr = QgsExpression("\"DI\"='1'")
selection = layer_DI.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
ids = [s.id() for s in selection]
layer_DI.selectByIds(ids)

# get the bounding box of the selected feature(s)
bbox = layer_DI.boundingBoxOfSelected()

# if the selection is a single point, the bounding box will not be a valid extent for the map item
# this is solved by growing the bbox by (50) map units (also useful for adding some padding space around features in the map)
bbox.grow(50)

# create the map
map = QgsLayoutItemMap(layout)
map.setRect(20,20,20,20)

ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([layer_DI]) # set layers to be mapped

# set the extent of the map to the bounding box of the selected feature(s)
ms.setExtent(bbox)
map.setExtent(bbox)

map.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255, 0))
layout.addLayoutItem(map)

map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(5, 20, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(180, 180, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code, but when I open my layout I get a message "current map display" and nothing is shown. I also tried to export it to an image to see if it worked but my image is empty

Comment: It is not the full code needed, just the selection and everything after. Did you add the first part?

Comment: Yes I did, I added the first part too

Comment: For me it works fine (using a different expression that works on the layer in my canvas). See screenshot I added.

Comment: It's weird. Look to my screenshot (https://imgur.com/a/LjNGxLs)

Comment: Can you show me your code please ?

Comment: Does your expression work properly and find at least one feature? I noticed that with an expression that did not return any features, my map looked like yours. I will add my complete code to my answer.

Comment: Yes my expression work properly, my feature appears selected in QGIS but it's not shown in my layout. I even tried with another layer and I got the same result. Here is a screenshot of my feature selected (https://imgur.com/a/FMqR3CE) and here is the result (https://imgur.com/QLvxik4). I was wondering if it's a problem of the scale of the map because when I open my layout and I select my map, at the right I have scale = nan. Is it the same thing for you ?

Comment: Ah okay, it is point data. The `boundingBoxOfSelected()` returns a bounding box of 0 size for a single point (the xMinimum and xMaximum are the same, and the yMinimum and yMaximum are the same).

Comment: I have added the solution to my answer. Use `bbox.grow(number_of_map_units)` to enlarge the bbox of the selected point. Be careful if you are using WGS84 as 50 will be 50 degrees, you will need something much smaller.

Comment: Aaah I see. It worked for me ! Thank you sooo much Matt.